# services running in a node

Tags: ros, services, parameters

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

I was wondering if its possible to get a list of all services to which a node is connected, either as a client or as a server.

Somethis similar to ros::this_node::getSubscribedTopics()

http://docs.ros.org/electric/api/roscpp/html/namespaceros_1_1this__node.html#a81620bbd1e0a3196d694c38fbd4dea8a

Also, is it possible to know which parameters a node has read.

Thanks

Miguel Oliveira

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/81436/services-running-in-a-node/) by [Miguel Riem de Oliveira](https://answers.ros.org/users/1178/miguel-riem-de-oliveira/) on ROS Answers with karma: 254 on 2013-09-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Miguel Riem de Oliveira](https://answers.ros.org/users/1178/miguel-riem-de-oliveira/) on 2013-10-01**:
Hi everyone

I found a workaround for this one.

I use the shell
ros service list api from ros.

To make a system call and then get back the result I use ipstream library.

Perhaps it is helpfull for someone.

PS: I just did not find a way to get the client services a node is connected to ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Miguel,

You need to call getSystemState(caller_id) from the ROS XMLRPC Master API, and it returns a list of all the subscribers, publishers, and services. The Master API documentation URL: wiki.ros.org/ROS/Master_API

Thanks,

Aaron

---

Originally posted by [unknown_entity1](https://answers.ros.org/users/4485/unknown_entity1/) with karma: 104 on 2013-10-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Miguel Riem de Oliveira](https://answers.ros.org/users/1178/miguel-riem-de-oliveira/) on 2013-10-22**:
Thanks for the answer Aaron. I'll do that. Miguel

**Comment by [unknown_entity1](https://answers.ros.org/users/4485/unknown_entity1/) on 2013-10-23**:
Your welcome! There are multiple deficiencies in the API related to Services. Including the inability to obtain the Service Topic Type, and the inability to request MD5 information for Topics/Services.